# iText7: How to use table.flush() and set a very wide page

Tags: itext7

I'm using iText7 (7.2.3) to generate PDF documents with wide tables. I need the table to completely appear on the page. These documents also contains tens of thousands of rows so, ideally, I'd like to be able to use a low memory footprint using table.flush() (see https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/large-tables).

Here's my actual code that works:

```
// At this point table contains all the table data
Text Title = new Text("Report Title")
    .SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD));

Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(Title).SetMargin(0);

table.SetBorderCollapse(BorderCollapsePropertyValue.SEPARATE);
table.SetNextRenderer(new CustomBorderTableRenderer(table));

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new(new PdfWriter(Filename));
Document doc = new(pdfDoc);

// calculate maximum width of document based on table width
float necessaryWidth = 523f;
IRenderer tableRenderer = table.CreateRendererSubTree().SetParent(doc.GetRenderer());
LayoutResult tableLayoutResult = tableRenderer.Layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, new Rectangle(necessaryWidth, 1000))));
float tableHeightTotal = tableLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetHeight();
float tableWidthTotal = tableLayoutResult.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetWidth();

// regenerate document with updated width
doc = new(pdfDoc, new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(tableWidthTotal, 1024));

doc.Add(p1);

doc.Add(table);

doc.Close();
```

It's a bit dirty because I first get all the table data (which can take a lot of memory) then check the table width inside the document and regenerate a new page with updated width. Only after that can I insert the table data in the page.
I feel it's kind of the chicken or the egg problem: if I know the page width in advance no problem I can use table.flush() but in order to get the table width I need to fill all the table first.

I think my best bet is to update the page width after all rows are inserted but I could not find a way to do this.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Would you mind sharing sample code generating your table? You mention it has tens of thousands of rows but you use `1000` as height in your code which looks strange - did you make this value smaller for the purpose of demonstration?

Comment: Regarding your comment itself, if you try to insert table parts partially then each part will use the width that it needs. But you need to make sure the column widths are the same for the whole table throughout. Therefore I don't think there is a way to update the page width after all rows are inserted really. For demonstration purposes you can try setting a big width (definitely bigger that will be ever needed) for the document in the first place and then add a table there - are you satisfied with the result? If so, then there is a way to update the page width.

Comment: Devil is in the details here, so ideally you should share completely reproducible code sample for the conversation to be not theoretical. Also, are you concert by the "dirtiness" of the code currently or e.g. memory footprint, runtime etc? I don't think that updating page size will be more "beautiful" than the approach you have now. If you don't have any concerns apart from that I'd say the code is okay

Comment: Data comes from database.

Code for inserting each row looks like:
            writer ??= new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(NbCols)).UseAllAvailableWidth();

                ((Table)writer).AddCell(new iText.Layout.Element.Cell().SetKeepTogether(true).Add(new Paragraph(field)).SetBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER));


As you can see I set the table number of columns here.
Again, without knowing in advance the number of records, how do I make the page wide enough for the table with the ability to call table.flush() to use less memory.

Comment: Let's just say I create my PDF document with one large table in it. After the table is added to the document I need to adjust the page width. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes. E.g. use `page.setCropBox()`